# Is there a way to use the puppet resource command for the vagrant provisioner?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Is it possible to use the `puppet resource` command to check the individual configuration of resources on nodes that have been provisioned with puppet in vagrant?  Or am I required to use a puppet server to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `puppet resource` command only requires that the agent/parser package (aka the `puppet` gem, whether installed via a package manager or not and AIO or not) be installed. It queries the current system state and provides the ability to convert it into Puppet resources. It does not require a server install or that Puppet was ever executed on the system. All that is required is for Puppet to be installed on a supported system.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/man/resource.html